# Generating texture coordinates autmatically with Cube Mapping for an object that is not a skybox in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, uv-mapping, cubemap

I am wondering whether its possible to automatically generate texture coordinates for custom obj models to work with cubemaps. Every tutorial I see online is about environment mapping. Is it possible to write a shader that allows me to generate UV's like in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jID5.jpg

So far I've loaded cubemap texture:

```
bool Texture::LoadCubicTexture(vector<string> filenameTable)
{
  glGenTextures(1,&texID);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,texID);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  int i = 0;
  vector<string>::iterator vsit;

  // There is always six filenames
  for(vsit=filenameTable.begin();vsit!=filenameTable.end();++vsit)
  {
    string filename = *vsit;
    BMPData* bmpData = LoadTextureBMPData_custom(filename);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+i,0,GL_RGB,bmpData->width,bmpData->height,0,GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&(bmpData->data[0]));
    i++;
    delete daneObrazu;
  }
  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

  return true;
}
```

I've also have my custom .obj posted online here:
https://pastebin.com/NVKgrGGZ

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cube_map_ogl_tutorial.html especially the paragraph *Mapping Texture Coordinates to Cube Map Faces*

Comment: Take the point you are trying to map and the center of your object and subtract them.